# How to scaling up with Akka

Tags: akka

I tested *10 routees* of **Akka Actor** in a machine and did the task I want (read from DB and make API call) in *3 minutes*. Then, I changed my configuration to create *50 routees* and it did the task in *equal minutes*.

I also increased the CPU and RAM of my VM but the time it took didnot go down. My plan is by increasing the CPU cores and RAM, I want to do the task in ***SHORTER*** time.
How do I achieve that?

Comment: Maybe your DB is the slow system in your architecture? Adding more routees doesn't mean your will get more throughput automatically. What kind of router are you using? What kind of dispatcher?

Comment: @hveiga You may be right. I am using MySql database and the routing mechanism I am using is smallest-mailbox-pool with Akka's default dispatcher. How can I use Akka's routing feature with MySql or Postgres DB?